# python win32gui finding child windows

Tags: python, win32gui

for example at first you have to find hwnd of skype

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'skype')
```

and than all his child windows and their titles

```
child = ???
```

any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code shows `hwnd` of EditPlus child windows that has `WindowsText` of some length:

**EDIT**

You will have to find `hwnd` of your application, and then use this handle with `EnumChildWindows`. I extended example code with it. Once you get application `hwnd` you can enumerate only its windows. When you give 0 as `hwnd` to `EnumChildWindows` you will get handles of all runing windows. Add some prints to my code and check it!

Extended code:

```
import win32gui

MAIN_HWND = 0

def is_win_ok(hwnd, starttext):
    s = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if s.startswith(starttext):
            print s
            global MAIN_HWND
            MAIN_HWND = hwnd
            return None
    return 1


def find_main_window(starttxt):
    global MAIN_HWND
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(0, is_win_ok, starttxt)
    return MAIN_HWND


def winfun(hwnd, lparam):
    s = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if len(s) > 3:
        print("winfun, child_hwnd: %d   txt: %s" % (hwnd, s))
    return 1

def main():
    main_app = 'EditPlus'
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, main_app)
    print hwnd
    if hwnd < 1:
        hwnd = find_main_window(main_app)
    print hwnd
    if hwnd:
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, winfun, None)

main()
```

Comment: im a little bit confused here ... when i turn on an aplication it returns main hwnd and tree childs despite the fact there are no child windows and when the application isnt running it prints far too many results when there shouldnt be any
btw is there a way to determinate whitch window is running under whitch process?